# Three different ways for upgrading MCU firmware

Tags: digital-logic, switches, multiplexer

I'm working on a controller board that uses RX66N as the microcontroller (MICRO). Basically there are lot of analogue signals to be measured and 12 ports of different communications. The MICRO works from a 3.3 V supply and at 12 MHz.

I should make three ways to upgrade the MICRO firmware: from an emulator, a user port or by the company cloud remotely.

I tried to make this more tangible in the diagrams below:

`RUN MODE MD=1`

[image]

`BOOT MODE MD=0 using USER MODBUS`
[image]

`BOOT MODE MD=0 using USER CLOUD`
[image]

This is the structure that I have.

I've thought to use a TI TMUX1309 to connect the needed signals to MICRO TDO & TDI. On the other side, I need to disconnect the SCI signals from the MICRO while they gonna be connected to TDO/TDI of the MCU.

I wanted to use SN74LVC2G66 of TI as the switch for disconnecting. But I have a doubt for the controlling signal of both MUX and switch. Is it possible to use the same control signal for both chips?

For the user port, I need to apply a kind of jumper to give it priority over the other ways for upgrading.

This is the first time that I've done this sort of circuit and it makes me really confused.

Comment: *I should have three ways to upgrade the device firmware* Please take a step back and edit your question to write an introduction that explains the system you're working on, what it does and what it's for. Your question is currently written as if everyone has the pre-knowledge of the 'the device' that you do.

Comment: I tried to make it better. Thanks

Comment: TDO & TDI are *JTAG* signals. You can't connect them to a UART ("RS232 USER" & 
CLOUD"). If you want to update your MCU's firmware over a UART, then you need it to have a bootloader which supports this method. Some MCUs have this built-in, while others do not.

Comment: I checked the microcontroller datasheet. It´s possible to connect the SCI siganls to TDO/TDI ports of the micro.

Comment: Now I need to use the MUX for connecting the lines to TDO/TDI of the micro and at the same time disconnect the SCI signals from the assigned pins to MICRO. I've thought to use two MUX one for connecting and the other one for disconnecting. Each MUX should be controlled by two signals. Now I'm working on how design these control pins for having the minimum pin assignments in MICRO. Any suggestion?